# Symfony forms - EntityType choose the choices by ID of entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

sorry for the language I'm bad in English, I'm actually creating a "pokemon game" for train me on symfony, the problem context is that i want to the user to select her first Pokemon among a list of pokemon, but I want that the user can only choose among three of them.

Example : Pokemon Entity contains 10 Pokemon. And my user can only choose between the pokemon number 1, 2 or 3.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Pokemon;
use App\Entity\CatchPokemon;
use App\Controller\PokemonController;
use App\Repository\PokemonRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ChooseStarterType extends AbstractType{
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

    $builder
        ->add('pokemonId', EntityType::class,[
            'class' => Pokemon::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'choices' => [
                function(PokemonRepository $pokemonRepository){ $pokemonRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1 ]); },
                function(PokemonRepository $pokemonRepository){ $pokemonRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 2 ]); },
                function(PokemonRepository $pokemonRepository){ $pokemonRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 3 ]); },
            ]
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => CatchPokemon::class,
    ]);
}
}
```

By default the EntityType show all of the Pokemon, so I added the attributes 'choices' with an array with the 3 ID of the pokemon that I want to be selectable. But that's didn't work, how can I do that please ?

Comment: Use the [`query_builder`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#ref-form-entity-query-builder) option to filter the resultset instead: `return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')->where('p.id IN(1,2,3)')`.

Comment: Ok thanks i will see that !